# how to resolve this exception ""Exception in thread main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"" when I use the jar?

Tags: java, class, exception, jar

I have a jar file that includes some class files and some dependent jars for that class files. When I try to use that jar file as library jar the main class call the class in dependent jar, at the time it show like

```
"Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError".
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this Exception.

Thanks in advance.

## Here this is my exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jclouds/compute/ComputeServiceContext

[Here I attached the image for jar file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4cZs.png)

Comment: does your jar file contains all other dependent jar's that is used by the class present in your jar file?

Comment: This means that you are missing something in the classpath, or that your JAR file has the wrong structure so that Java can't find the class files in the JAR in the place where it expects it. How are you compiling your code, creating your JAR file and running your program (what commands exactly are you using)? Are your classes in the right directories (matching the package structure) in your JAR file?

Comment: You can look at the exact contents of your jar with `unzip -t my.jar` (the `jar` tool will also work, though I'm less familiar with it).  If an expected class is missing (particularly the one the error is complaining about, assuming it tells you), then there's a smoking gun.

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvarj,Yes the jar file contain all dependent jars used by the class in my jar file.

Comment: can you post full stack of your exception?

Comment: @Jesper,Yes the jar structure is some classes in main package and dependent jars.

Comment: @Steve,but the expected class is in the dependent jar when i extract the contents of the jar.

Comment: @Jesper, I have created a jar using maven. And I include the structure of created jar in my post.